# How can I pass a string in the click event with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

How can I pass a calculated string to a function in AngularJS ?

Here's the code that I have:

```
<div ng-click="wos.wordFormRowClicked(wf)"
     ng-form="wos.wordFormNgForm_{{wf.wordFormIdentity}}"
     ng-repeat="wf in wos.word.wordForms">
        <div>
            <div ng-click="wos.wordFormDefinitionRowClicked(d)"
                 ng-repeat="d in wf.wordDefinitions">
                <div>
                    <span ng-click="wos.wordFormDeleteDefinition("wos.wordFormNgForm_{{wf.wordFormIdentity}}", wf.wordFormId, d.wordDefinitionId)"
                          ></span>
                </div>
```

I'm trying to pass a string as the 1st parameter of the function `wos.wordFormDeleteDefinition` but it is giving me a run time error. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the string to be interpolated, pass the expression and the string as 2 differnt values to function and handle them in your controller:

```
<span ng-click="wos.wordFormDeleteDefinition('wos.wordFormNgForm_', wf.wordFormIdentity, wf.wordFormId, d.wordDefinitionId)"
                      ></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this - initialize a new model `str_param` using `ng-init`

```
<span ng-init="str_param = (wos.wordFormNgForm_{{wf.wordFormIdentity}} | toString)" 
ng-click="wos.wordFormDeleteDefinition(str_param, wf.wordFormId, d.wordDefinitionId)">
</span>
```

**PS:** I am not sure what these values are, if the above code fails, try removing the `{{}}` and `| toString` to see if that works.